# Using a single Moq Setup to return multiple argument values

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have a Moq object and I need to return values for 4 different arguments. I can do it in 4 different statements but is there a way to achieve the same in a single Setup statement?

```
var parametersMock = new Mock<IParameters>();

parametersMock.Setup(x => x.Year).Returns(2023);
parametersMock.Setup(x => x.IsFirstTime).Returns(true);
parametersMock.Setup(x => x.IsValid).Returns(true);
parametersMock.Setup(x => x.IsTest).Returns(false);
```

Is it possible to achieve the same in a single mock setup like below:

```
parametersMock.Setup(x => x.Year, x.IsFirstTime, x.IsValid, x.IsTest).Returns(2023).Returns(true).Returns(true).Returns(false);
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can use `SetupSequence()` to set up sequential calls for the same method/propertiy and the same argument, but not for different methods/properties and different arguments. Why would you even want to do that? The setup you have is clear and understandable. Why make it more difficult to read than necessary?

Comment: What's the purpose of your `IParameters` interface in the first place? If instances serve as configuration objects that only hold references or values, why would there be an interface? You wouldn't even need to use a `Mock<IParameters>`, but instead pass an instance of the implementation to use in your test.

Comment: @Julian, Currently the setup looks clean as I've mentioned only 4 arguments in the above example, but I would need to pass 26 parameters like this, so writing this in 26 separate lines doesn't seem that good, but if there was a way to pass it in a single Mock setup, I can still format it in such a way that there would be 5 arguments per line, so it's still better than having 26 lines is what I was thinking.

Comment: Don't optimize for convenience and don't sacrifice readability for shortness. Taking shortcuts for the wrong reasons only makes the (test) code difficult to maintain and change. 26 parameters also sounds like an awful lot, maybe there's a way to reduce the amount of parameters or use sensible default values?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your test code is becoming totally unreadable.

Comment: @Jagath If your method really takes 26 different parameters, there's this problem to solve first.

Answer (score 4):

When your interface represents a data model like this, as opposed to a logic-heavy "service" class, it's usually easier to create your own class that implements the interface via settable properties.

```
class FakeParameters : IParameters
{
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public bool IsFirstTime {get;set;}
    public bool IsValid{get;set;}
    public bool IsTest{get;set;}
}

// ...
var parameters = new FakeParameters
{
    Year = 2023,
    IsFirstTime = true,
    IsValid = true,
    IsTest = false
};
```

You may want to consider your reasons for having IParameters be an interface anyway: usually for basic data model classes like this, there's more value in just using a concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Mock.Of` to setup multiple properties with a single command

```
var paramsMock = Mock.Of<IParameters>(m =>
    m.Year == 2023 &&
    m.IsFirstTime == true &&
    m.IsValid == true &&
    m.IsTest == false);
```